# python question about running a main function

Tags: python

sup i'm pretty bad at this but i'm trying to learn python but i don't really understand why this isn't working. all i want to do is run an unordered sequential search but nothing happens when i run this.

```
def sequentialSearch(alist, item):
    pos = 0
    found = False

    while pos < len(alist) and not found:
        if alist[pos] == item:
            found = True
        else:
            pos = pos+1

    return found

def main():
    alist = random.sample(range(0, 1000000), 10000)
    sequentialSearch(alist[0:1000], 9)

main()
```

manually typing this in the python shell works though

```
>>> alist = random.sample(range(0, 1000000), 10000)
>>> sequentialSearch(alist[0:1000], 9)
False
```

i know i'm missing something small and dumb but i can't seem to fix it lol

Comment: Welcome! You should call `print()` to output result to console.

Comment: Your code does not print anything. But the **interactive shell** has the feature to print the result of the last entered commanf if it is not `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to print this or return it, or whatever you would like to do.

```
print(sequentialSearch(alist[0:1000], 9))
```